# Grouping the column with specified logic in R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I have a data frame with 1000's record for many employee and I would like to group the employee based on the Months column such that I can calculate mean for the 1st,2nd,3rd months and if the employee has experienced in months column then group it such that only the **1st experienced value is considered for each employee and then take the mean for those value only** for month_1,month_2 and month_3 normal grouping needs to be done and then take the mean for those values.

Please find below the data frame total

```
name <-c("tom","harry","tom","tom","tom","tom","harry","harry","tom","harry","harry","harry"
         ,"sam","sam","sam","sam","sam","tim","tim")
name<-as.data.frame(name)
months<-c("Month_0","Month_1","Month_1","Month_2","Month_3","Experienced","Month_2","Month_3","Experienced","Experienced","Experienced","Experienced","Month_0","Month_1","Month_2","Month_3","Experienced","Month_2","Experienced")
months<-as.data.frame(months)
values <-c(10,1,20,30,40,50,2,3,60,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,100,400)
values<-as.data.frame(values)
total<-cbind(name,months,values)
```

i tried using dplyr
`total<-total%>%group_by(months)%>%mutate(average = mean(values)`
but this takes mean of all the experience values , However I need only the 1st experienced value and then there mean value.

Please find below the input and output snapshot
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
require(dplyr)

total %>% 
    group_by(months) %>% 
    filter(!duplicated(name)) %>% 
    summarise(average = mean(values))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  months      average
  <fct>         <dbl>
1 Experienced  115.  
2 Month_0        5.5 
3 Month_1        7.67
4 Month_2       33.8 
5 Month_3       15.7
```

`!duplicated(name)` will by default keep the first value.

Comment: nope this will group every experienced value , I am looking for 1st experienced value

Answer (score 1):

This can help you:

```
library(dplyr)

total %>% filter(!duplicated(paste0(name,months,fromLast=T)))%>%
  group_by(months)%>%summarise(average = mean(values))

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  months      average
  <fct>         <dbl>
1 Experienced  115.  
2 Month_0        5.5 
3 Month_1        7.67
4 Month_2       33.8 
5 Month_3       15.7
```

Answer (score 1):

in Base R

```
means <- aggregate(values ~ months, total, mean)
means[means$months == "Experienced",2] <- mean(with( total[total$months=="Experienced",], tapply(values,name, function(x) x[1])))

       months     values
1 Experienced 114.750000
2     Month_0   5.500000
3     Month_1   7.666667
4     Month_2  33.750000
5     Month_3  15.666667
```